Python (Polars): Vectorized operation of determining current solution with the use of previous variables
Let's say we have 3 variables a, b & c.
There are n instances of each, and all but the first instance of c are null.
We are to calculate each next c based on a given formula comprising of only present variables on the right hand side:
c = [(1 + a) * (current_c) * (b)] + [(1 + b) * (current_c) * (a)]
How do we go about this calculation without using native python looping?
I've tried:

pl.int_range(my_index_column_value, pl.len() + 1) (my index starts form 1)
pl.rolling(...) (this seems to be quite an expensive operation)
pl.when(...).then(...).otherwise(...) with the above two along with .over(...) & pl.select(...).item()

to no avail. It's always the case that _the shift has already been fully made at once. I thought perhaps the most plausible way to do this would be either rolling by 1 with grouping by 2, or via pl.int_range(...) and using the current index column number as the shift value. However, these keep failing as I am unable to properly come up with the correct syntax - I'm unable to pass the index column value and have polars accept it as a number. Even casting throws the same errors. Right now I am thinking we could manage another row for shifting and passing values back to row c, but then again, I'm not sure if this would even be an efficient way to go about it...
What would be the most optimal way to go about this without offloading to Rust?
Code for reference:
import polars as pl

if __name__ == "__main__":
    initial_c_value = 3

    df = pl.DataFrame(((2, 3, 4, 5, 8), (3, 7, 4, 9, 2)), schema=('a', 'b'))
    df = df.with_row_index('i', 1).with_columns(pl.lit(None).alias('c'))

    df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('i') == 1)
    .then(
        (((1 + pl.col('a')) * (initial_c_value) * (pl.col('b'))) +
        ((1 + pl.col('b')) * (initial_c_value) * (pl.col('a')))).alias('c'))
    .otherwise(
        ((1 + pl.col('a')) * (pl.col('c').shift(1)) * (pl.col('b'))) +
        ((1 + pl.col('b')) * (pl.col('c').shift(1)) * (pl.col('a')))).shift(1).alias('c'))

    print(df)


You can't replicate recursion with Expressions. Try numba like this, this, or this

RE: Rust, it is done with .scan() e.g. https://marcogorelli.github.io/polars-plugins-tutorial/cum_sum/ - Discussed in https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12165

Using numba you can make ufuncs which polars can use seamlessly.
from numba import guvectorize, int64
import polars as pl

@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64[:], int64, int64[:])], '(n),(n),()->(n)', nopython=True)
def make_c(a,b,init_c, res):
    res[0]=(1+a[0]) * init_c * b[0] + (1+b[0]) * init_c * a[0]
    for i in range(1,a.shape[0]):
        res[i] = (1+a[i]) * res[i-1] * b[i] + (1+b[i]) * res[i-1] * a[i]
        
df = pl.DataFrame(((2, 3, 4, 5, 8), (3, 7, 4, 9, 2)), schema=('a', 'b'))

df.with_columns(
    c=make_c(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b'), 3)
)
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 51        │
│ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 2652      │
│ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 106080    │
│ 5   ┆ 9   ┆ 11032320  │
│ 8   ┆ 2   ┆ 463357440 │
└─────┴─────┴───────────┘

The way it works is that the ufunc detects that its input is a polars Expr (ie pl.col() is an Expr) and then it hands control to polars. Because of that you can NOT just do make_c('a','b',3) as then its input is just a str and it won't know what to do with that.

i'm still comprehending your excellent answer, what would happen though, if i were to offload this to a c module - if the routine is running a huge number of times, would the interop defeat the purpose of that type of implementation anyway?

do you have an idea as to what this warning might be? CustomUFuncWarning: Native numpy ufuncs are dispatched using `map_batches(ufunc, is_elementwise=True)` which is safe for native Numpy and Scipy ufuncs but custom ufuncs in a group_by context won't be properly grouped. Custom ufuncs are dispatched with is_elementwise=False. If make_c needs elementwise then please use map_batches directly.   return self.ufunc(\*args, \*\*kwargs)

I'm not sure what you mean on the first part. Polars and numpy can do copy free interop so there isn't much to gain beyond using numba. As to that warning, it's meant to tell people that, unlike numpy's built in ufuncs, custom ones from numba won't work in streaming.

Unfortunately, there's no reduce operation which would work vertically in polars. You can use cumulative_eval() but it operates on the whole window so you'd need to recalculate all the elements every time.
One way of doing it would be to use common table expressions of duckdb:
import duckdb

duckdb.sql(f"""
with recursive cte(i,a,b,c) as (
    select
        i, a, b,
        (1 + a) * ({initial_c_value} * b) + (1 + b) * ({initial_c_value} * a) as c
    from df
    where i = 1
    
    union all

    select
        df.i, df.a, df.b,
        (1 + df.a) * (cte.c * df.b) + (1 + df.b) * (cte.c * df.a) as c
    from cte
        inner join df on
            df.i = cte.i + 1
)
select * from cte
""").pl()

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ i   ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 51        │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 2652      │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 106080    │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 9   ┆ 11032320  │
│ 5   ┆ 8   ┆ 2   ┆ 463357440 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘

another way would be to use numba:
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.int64, nb.int64[:])], '(n),(n),()->(n)', nopython=True)
def calc(a, b, c0, c):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        c[i] = (1 + a[i]) * (c0 * b[i]) + (1 + b[i]) * (c0 * a[i])
        c0 = c[i]

df.with_columns(c = calc(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b'), initial_c_value))

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ i   ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 51        │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   ┆ 2652      │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 106080    │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 9   ┆ 11032320  │
│ 5   ┆ 8   ┆ 2   ┆ 463357440 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘


One potential gotcha is that when you use a global variable in your compiled func then its hardcoded when you compile. That means if you subsequently change initial_c_value the function will still use the same value as when you defined/compiled it.

Thank you, that’s useful. I’ll update the answer

ah so this is called reduce huh? thank you for your suggestions. if reduce does not work vertically, what if i reshape the dataframe (it will be costly)? also, you reminded me of something i was considering. the awfully named cumfold(...). btw @DeanMacGregor i'm still comprehending your excellent answer, what would happen though, if i were to offload this to a c module - if the routine is running a huge number of times, would the interop defeat the purpose of that type of implementation anyway?

You could write a rust extension

i'll try numba and if things don't work out, it seems there's no other choice but to go rust... if this routine runs multiple times, will there be any additional interop overhead from the extra module, you reckon?
