Is there an exponentially weighted moving sum (ewms instead of ewma) function in polars
Also here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17602
In polars ewm_mean, the update is formulated as:
y = (1 - alpha) * y + alpha * x

I found that sometimes it is useful to use non-decayed update, a.k.a. exponentially weighted moving sum instead:
y = (1 - alpha) * y + x

ewms is merely a simple multiple (1 / alpha) of ewma for equal time lapse but not so trivial when updates are not equally spaced
To achieve this I implement some update function on myself and try to use .map_batches() but think it's rather suboptimal.
Is there a better alternative?
def ems_iter(values: np.array, intervals: Union[np.array, float], half_lifes: Union[np.array, float]):
    """
    >>> ems_iter([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 1, 1)
    [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 1.125, 0.5625, 0.28125]
    """
    res = []
    agg = 0.
    values = np.array(values)
    decays = (1/2) ** (np.array(intervals) / half_lifes)
    decays = np.ones(values.shape) * decays
    for value, decay in zip(values, decays):
        agg = agg * decay + value
        res.append(agg)
    return res

def ems(val_col: str, interval_col: str, hl: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return (
        pl.struct([col, interval_col])
        .map_batches(
            lambda x: pl.Series(
                ems_iter(
                    x.struct.field(col),
                    x.struct.field('lapse').dt.total_seconds(),
                    hl
                )
            )
        )
    )




not yet - could you open a feature request on the polars github please?

@ignoring_gravity added here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17602

You'd get significantly better performance if you rewrote that as a gufunc with numba. Here are a couple examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78484792/python-polars-vectorized-operation-of-determining-current-solution-with-the-u/78485173#78485173 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000439/cum-max-sum-in-polars/77001362#77001362 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567521/optimize-computation-of-similarity-scores-by-executing-native-polars-command-ins/77571420#77571420
